# Sharding embedded document in spring-data-mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using the sharding support of spring-data-mongodb by adding the @Sharded annotation on a document:

```
@Sharded(immutableKey = true, shardKey = { "location.locationId", "ts" })
```

However, when spring-data is generating the request, the added filter contains:

```
filterWithShardKey = {Document@20158}  size = 3
 "_id" -> {ObjectId@20139} "60489730a9687c7c83a287df"
 "location.locationId" -> null
 "ts" -> {Date@20141} "Mon Feb 17 12:13:06 CET 2020"
```

I looked over the QueryOperations class and its applyShardKey method:

```
getMappedShardKeyFields(domainType).forEach(key -> filterWithShardKey.putIfAbsent(key, shardKeySource.get(key)));
```

shardKeySource is a bson document and presents the nested documents also as bson documents (not flat). Hence, when getting the "location.locationId" field, it is not found:

```
documentAsMap = {LinkedHashMap@20083}  size = 9
 "_id" -> {ObjectId@20099} "60489996721f557bb2c8e5d6"
 "ts" -> {Date@20101} "Mon Feb 17 12:13:06 CET 2020"
 "location" -> {Document@20103}  size = 3
  key = "location"
  value = {Document@20103}  size = 3
 "source" -> {Document@20105}  size = 7
 "device" -> {Document@20107}  size = 2
 "timezoneRawOffset" -> {Double@20109} 1.0
```

Is there a way to declare a nested sharding key with spring-data-mongodb?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you please open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues). It sounds like we should resolve dot paths within the document to get the value.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. GH issue is created here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3590